# Why is my UINavigationController starting with the second view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here's what I've got:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ...

  //create two vc's.....
  APCMainViewController *mainViewController = [[APCMainViewController alloc] init];
  APCVideosTableViewController *videosViewController = [[APCVideosTableViewController alloc] init];

  //create the main nav controller....
  UINavigationController *mainNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
  mainNav.viewControllers = @[mainViewController, videosViewController];

  self.window.rootViewController = mainNav;

  ...
}
```

But the app always starts with videosViewController showing, not the mainViewController.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by removing the following line of code

```
mainNav.viewControllers = @[mainViewController, videosViewController]; // Not required
```

You are initialising the navigation view controller with your root view controller(`mainViewController`) and which is your first view controller to show. Then no need of adding view controller again to the stack.

Comment: I agree with you anil. But may be the OP wants to specify the navigation stack before hand?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

when you set a rootController
The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.

Assigning a new array of view controllers to this property is equivalent to calling the setViewControllers:animated: method with the animated parameter set to NO.

So this would mean, you are calling setViewControllers; which shows in the documentation:

The view controllers to place in the stack. The front-to-back order of the controllers in this array represents the new bottom-to-top order of the controllers in the navigation stack. **Thus, the last item added to the array becomes the top item of the navigation stack.**

That should give you a clue of why your navigation stack is upside down.

So it should be

```
mainNav.viewControllers = @[videosViewController, mainViewController ];
```